# How can I change the width of an element dynamically every time I call a function?

Tags: javascript, css, width

```
    if (parseInt(numberField.value) === correctAnswer) {
    state.score += 1;
    pointsNeeded.textContent = 10 - state.score;
    updateProblem();
    progressState.style.width += `${10}%`;
  } else {
    state.wrongAnswers += 1;
    mistakesAllowed.textContent = 2 - state.wrongAnswers;
    updateProblem();
  }
  checkLogic();
};
```

> I want to add on to the existing width dynamically, but the following code changes the width once and then suddenly stops doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with the line. `` progressState.style.width += `${10}%`; ``

On doing a console log, it's outputting below values:

```
10%
10%10%
10%10%
10%10%
```

Possible solution would be:

```
progressState.style.width = `${Number(progressState.style.width.replace("%",""))+10}%`;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. On doing that, it still console logs the same thing as you said earlier.

Comment: No, there isn't. It just logs the value that you just specified above. Anyway, this time I tried changing the transform property(scalex) and apparently it worked. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only assign width with %, replace this line

```
progressState.style.width += `${10}%`;
```

with

```
const width = progressState.style.width ? parseInt(progressState.style.width) : 0;
progressState.style.width = (width + 10) + '%';
```